# How to start a second timer after the first timer expires in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise, vuex

I have a Vue project, and in the Vuex store I have these states:

```
state: {
  gameStartTimer: 5,
  counter: false,
  randomNumber: Number,
  clickAlert: false
}
```

Now, in the `actions`, I have the following:

```
actions: {
    async startCounter({ state }) {
      state.counter = true;
      state.clickAlert = false;
      while (state.gameStartTimer > 0 && state.counter) {

        // this sets the timer to count down from 5 to 0
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (state.counter)
          state.gameStartTimer--;

        // the if-statement ensures nowTime is acquired upon gameStartTimer reaches 0
        if (state.gameStartTimer == 0) {
          let timeNow = new Date().getTime();
          state.nowTime = timeNow;
        }
      }
      state.counter = false;

      // I want to start a second timer here which counts down every second 
      // until the randomNumber state reaches 0
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (state.clickAlert)
          state.randomNumber--;

        if (state.randomNumber == 0) {
          state.clickAlert = true;
        }
      }

    },
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the first timer is enveloped in a while-loop, which is what I want, so that the game starts counting down from 5 to 0.

Then, I want a second timer (randomNumber is used for the duration) to run in the background, then turn the clickAlert state to true.

However, I could not get the second timer to run at all inside an async/await method. I am not quite sure what the syntax or logic problem is.

Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution seems to be to just wrap the second timer in a `while` loop too.

```
while (state.randomNumber > 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    state.randomNumber--;

    if (state.randomNumber === 0) {
        state.clickAlert = true;
    }
}
```

`async/await` is just a way to avoid callback functions. It's functionally equivalent to this:

```
while (state.randomNumber > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        state.randomNumber--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested that before and it didn't work (it works in reality, by the way, just that it got a bug and that this issue was secondary to another which I have just discovered). The real issue was that the count down was counting down in milliseconds rather than seconds, that's why the clickAlert never changed (or rather it will change but I would have to wait 1,000 seconds). Looks like a simple issue to resolve - the main problem was that I didn't discover this issue until now. Thank you for confirming the syntax/logic though! It helped!